# Cannot install rerun gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When I tried the following command

```
gem install rerun
```

I got this error:

```
http://rubygems.org/ does not appear to be a repository
Could not find a valid gem 'rerun' (>= 0) in any repository
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Your Rubygems version is probably outdated and no longer supported. You can update it with:

```
gem install rubygems-update
update_rubygems
gem update --system
```

It may be that you need `sudo` for this.

Comment: Thanks. Installed rubygems-update but when I tried update_rubygems I see an error "/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rubygems-update-1.3.7/lib/rubygems/source_index.rb:68:in `installed_spec_directories': undefined method `path' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)"

Comment: Seems like a known issue: http://help.rubygems.org/discussions/problems/445-gem-update-system-fails-undefined-method-path-for-gemmodule-nomethoderror can you try to re-install Ruby?